# How can I overwrite Google service account credentials in spark config?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform

The application is already have service account set up in the core-site.xml

I'm trying to overwrite it during application execution by setting Google service account credentials but it's failing with this error.

Sample code:

```
spark.conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "gs://<bucket Name>")
spark.conf.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.private.key.id", "<private key id>")
spark.conf.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.email", "<service account email>")
spark.conf.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.private.key", "<private key>")
val df = spark.read.csv("gs://test/test.csv")
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A JSON key file may not be specified at the same time as credentials via configuration.
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:141)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.CredentialConfiguration.getCredential(CredentialConfiguration.java:106)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.getCredential(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1613)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.createGcsFs(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1699)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.configure(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1658)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.initialize(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:683)
  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.initialize(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:646)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2796)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:99)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2830)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2812)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:390)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:705)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$15.apply(DataSource.scala:389)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$15.apply(DataSource.scala:389)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:388)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:596)
```

How can this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done via using unset method in `hadoopConfiguration`

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.unset("fs.gs.auth.service.account.json.keyfile")
```

Any service account key set via conf in spark submit or set in core-site.xml can only be unset from `hadoopConfiguration.unset`